# string subscript out of range error in word capitalization

Tags: c++, arrays, string, capitalization

**Actually, the program works fine in Devc++ but gives me the error if i run it in VisualStudio, does anybody know why this happens?**

*The program should check if it has to cout a string from the **stati** array with every first letter of each word capitalized and then it has to convert the string back to lowercase, **statoScelto[]** just checks if the string has to be printed.*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {

    std::string stati[4] = { "italia", "francia", "spagna", "bosnia erzegovina" };
    bool statoScelto[4] = { true, false, false, true };
    int i, k;
    
    // here there is other code that eventually changes statoScelto[] values.
    
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if (statoScelto[i] == true) {
            stati[i][0] = toupper(stati[i][0]);

            for (k = 0; k < 16; k++) {
                if (stati[i][k] == ' ') {                          
                    stati[i][k + 1] = toupper(stati[i][k + 1]);
                }
            }

            std::cout << "\n" << stati[i];

            for (k = 0; k < 16; k++) {
                if (stati[i][k] == ' ') {                            
                    stati[i][k + 1] = tolower(stati[i][k + 1]);
                }
            }

            stati[i][0] = tolower(stati[i][0]);
        }
    }
    
    system("pause>0");
}
```

*as it is now, the program should print:*

*Italia*

*Bosnia Erzegovina*

*but when it is run a string subscript out of range error would pop up.
Does anybody understand what is wrong with it?*

Comment: Lots of magic numbers in this code, who knows if they are correct.  Please post a [mre].

Comment: A note on the [mre]: They can be hard to make, but they are worth it. MRE is a powerful debugging technique and you rarely have to finish the job before the reduced noise around the bug allows you to see and fix the bug. If you make a MRE early in the question-asking process, the process usually comes to a quick end.

Comment: @user4581301 I think the question is complete now, could you please tell me if you understand the problem or have any ideas?

Comment: @akaManen I've voted to re-open the question, but the second point in Bleh's answer is correct. the `16` should be `stati[i].size()` or you should use a [range-based `for` loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) so the number of iterations becomes controlled by the system for you. Code you don't have to write has no bugs. Or if it does, at least they aren't YOUR bugs.

Comment: @user4581301 Replacing 16 with stati[i].size() fixed everything, if you write it in an answer i'll accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things wrong with your code :

1. you need to place double quotes around the string characters you've defined .
   For example:
   std::string colour[4] = { "Blue", "Red",
   "Orange", "Yellow" };
2. The size 16 makes sense for the last word , where size is 16, but for all the other words, you're still trying to access the  positions which do not exist.
   maybe set a variable to the size of each word to solve this problem .

you could also put the if (stati[i][k] == ' ') condition before the loop, so it enters in only that case

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/array-strings-c-3-different-ways-create/ is 5 ways to correctly define  a string array